# SOAP Integration into WP PHP Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, soap

I'm tasked at using SOAP to pull in data through a WP Plugin for ease of use. **I'm stuck at using the supplied auth details to get the correct data**. I'm using SOAPUI to explore the request and see the possible methods/calls.

The flow should be using the **FetchNewListingsIds** which will give me a list of IDS which I can then put into an array object and then use that again for **FetchListings** with the supplied IDs - that will then give me all the details for each listing which I can then take and pull in to display

This is what I've written so far:

```
function property_feed_call(){

$url = "https://exdev.server.propctrl.com/v5.4/Basic/AgencyIntegration.svc?wsdl";

$user = "MindesExdevFeedUser";
$pass = "MindesExdevFeedUser";

$options = [
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'          => 1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
        [
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ]
        ]
    )
];

// Set request params
$params = array(
    "Username" => $user,
    "Password" => $pass,
);

$client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
$session = $client->FetchNewListingIds($params);


// Invoke WS method (Function1) with the request params 
$response = $client->__soapCall("FetchListings", array($params));

// Print WS response
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($session);
echo '</pre>';

}
```

An example of how the request looks (**FetchListings**) when I open it up with SOAPUI is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v5="http://server.propctrl.com/v5_4" xmlns:ais="http://server.propctrl.com/v5_4/AIS" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v5:Credentials>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v5:Password>?</v5:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v5:Username>?</v5:Username>
      </v5:Credentials>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ais:FetchListings>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ais:mandateIds>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <arr:int>?</arr:int>
         </ais:mandateIds>
      </ais:FetchListings>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So you can see its asking for Credentials which I have just not sure how to pass it to my request. And then for a **mandateIds** which I can get from another method that also requires the same Credentials.

Comment: Can you add an example of how the XML request should look like? Can you provide a link to the wsdl source, so that we can see how the `FetchListings` method is structured and what parameteres (structs) one should use?

Comment: Hey @Marcel thanks for getting back to me - I've added in an example of how the method is structured hopefully that helps you understand if not let me know I can adjust it.